# Conversion from String to SqlDbType.Ntext

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

In my code I have a string which looks like that:
`FoNa:S:0:8:SuNa:S:9:6:FaNa:S:7:9:BiDa:S:10:10:EAd:S:11:24:pCo:S:25:8:`
And in my SQL table I have a field with `Ntext` property.
While I'm trying to pass the string value as

```
dbHandler.SQLComm.Parameters.Add("@PropertyNames", SqlDbType.NText).Value = QueryName
```

it throws me the error of:
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
I Assume that is coming from the type of the field... but I'not sure for it...
Is someone which will assist me on this?

*** ADDITIONAL INFO'S ***

Here is the context:

```
srvHandler.SQLComm.Parameters.Add("@ApplicationName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1024).Value = MyAspNetSqlMembershipProvider.pApplicationName
dbHandler.SQLComm.Parameters.Add("@PropertyNames", SqlDbType.NText).Value = QueryName
dbHandler.SQLComm.Parameters.Add("@PropertyValuesString", SqlDbType.NText).Value = QueryValuesNames
```

Comment: Please show the exception's stack trace

Comment: at hellasdd.HDD.InnerApplications.RegisterMenus.CreateUserProfile(Guid UserGuid, Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Work\Adata\WEB SITES\NewHDD\hellasdd\hellasdd\Classes\Internet.vb:line 4390

Comment: Make this part of the question, it will be easier for people to provide assistance.

Comment: It could be a few things.  Maybe your dbHandler is nothing or SQLComm is nothing.  Did you check that?

Comment: Yes and they are working fine. `Dim dbHandler As New DBHandler` which is a class and the SQLComm is declared inside of the method

Comment: Can you narrow it down a bit? What I mean is can you create a Parameter in one line and then attempt to add it to dbHandler.SQLComm.Parameters in another?

Comment: this dbHandler is working in all of my code... in all of the table and procedure handling... and it works in the previous line...

Comment: But it would help to break it up if only for the purposes of diagnosing where the problem is. I would attempt to create the parameter in one line of code, set its value in the next and add it to parameters in the next. This would help focus where things are going wrong.

Comment: The line above the one you have trouble with is using 'srvHandler' not dbHandler.??

Comment: @RickS The error in my code was your point... thank you very much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly one of the following is null: `dbHandler` or `dbHandler.SQLComm`.

Add the following above the faulting code line:

```
Debug.Assert(dbHandler IsNot Nothing)
Debug.Assert(dbHandler.SQLComm IsNot Nothing)
```

Then try debugging again. If it breaks on either of these lines you'll have your answer.

Otherwise your code looks okay to me. `String` values can be passed as NText parameters this way.

**EDIT:**

After formatting your code it becomes evident that `srvHandler` should have been used instead of `dbHandler`. :)

Comment: Yes That is what I did... and I got the error in the above line... Line 4930 is the related one.

Comment: I edit my question as well...there you may see that in the previous line it works fine

Comment: Well that *is* odd. Have you tried adding Debug.Assert? It seems like it should work, but just in case the dbHandler state changed at one point or anything...

Comment: Just for kicks, try asserting that MyAspNetSqlMembershipProvider IsNot Nothing either.

Comment: You Have absolute RIGHT with no any reason in this line the SQLComm is nothing....

Comment: Whew! :p Next step from there would be to set a breakpoint on SQLComm setter property. Or reader.

Comment: In previous line it works and suddenly in this line stops... is nothing

Comment: Likely there's something unsuspected that changes dbHandler state somewhere. As I said your best bet will be to set breakpoints on whatever sets or resets SQLComm property. From inside your dbHandler type class.

Comment: Ahhh, of course! I missed that. This is why formatting helps. ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48622/discussion-between-lefteris-gkinis-and-crono)

Answer (score 2):

What about trying this:

```
dbHandler.SQLComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PropertyNames", QueryName)
```

If this doesn't work then it's definitely either dbHandler is nothing or SQLComm is nothing